# Where to put information from `key` entry of OpenVPN config file in pfSense?

Tags: freebsd, openvpn, ssl, certificates, pfsense

I have the following config file which works well with native OpenVPN client

```
client
dev tap

proto udp
port 1198

remote myhost.com 1194

persist-key
persist-tun


tls-client

ca   my-ca.crt
cert my-client.crt
key  my-client.key

verb 3
```

Now I want to configure pfSense OpenVPN client with the same info.

I don't understand, where to put `key` file content? I put `crt` files into appropriate section from `System/Certificate Manager`.

In client config page I see `Cryptographic Settings/Key` section with subnote `Paste the shared key here`. This section doesn't exist initially, but appears only after config saved once. When it appears, it contain some key. If I paste content of `key` file there, I get an error

`The field 'TLS Authentication Key' does not appear to be valid`

How to enter this file information?

**UPDATE**

If I make autogeneration, it creates

```
#
# 2048 bit OpenVPN static key
#
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
... small amount of HEX symbols ...
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
```

while my own key is

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
... large amount of random chars...
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I have checked my own key with `openssl` and it said it is 2048 bit. How it can be larger than autogenerated key, which is also entitled 2048 bit?

**UPDATE 2**

If I leave autogenerated key, it saves, but I have the following messages in `log`

```
TLS Error: cannot locate HMAC in incoming packet from
```

If I disable `TLS authentication - Enable authentication of TLS packets` then it also saves, but I have

```
Mar 16 22:25:39 openvpn 47325   Exiting due to fatal error
Mar 16 22:25:39 openvpn 47325   FreeBSD ifconfig failed: external program exited with error status: 1
Mar 16 22:25:39 openvpn 47325   /sbin/ifconfig ovpnc5 XX.XX.XX.XX netmask 255.255.255.0 mtu 1500 up
Mar 16 22:25:39 openvpn 47325   do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Mar 16 22:25:39 openvpn 47325   TUN/TAP device /dev/tap5 opened
```

In both case `key` file remain unused.

**UPDATE 3**

If I prepend the my key with the same

```
 -----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
```

line (and end with same), then GUI accepts the key, while in log I get the following error

```
Non-Hex character ('M') found at line 2 in key file '/var/etc/openvpn/client5.tls-auth' (0/128/256 bytes found/min/max)
```

so, it wants very specific key, but doesn't inform about it and document it.

Comment: You're in the correct place.  Mine works.  Check for any hidden additional characters and ensure your line endings are not Windows style CR/LF.  Did you retain the `-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----` and the equivalent closing line?

Comment: If it already contains the key, then maybe it's already set up, and you don't need to change it? Did you try without changing that one?

Comment: @garethTheRed I tried to fix line endings, but probably failed

Comment: @tomasz I can leave autogenerated key, but then I won't use all information I was given. Also connection doesn't happen this way.

Comment: The keys at both ends have to be the same. How about copying the autogenerated key to the VPN client?  I have `key-direction 1` at the client end.

Comment: @garethTheRed I don't control the server, I am trying to configure the client for existing server. I was able to configure OpenVPN client on Windows and now want to configure client on `pfSense`. I can't move any information FROM it.

Comment: Do the directions in this gist help you at all? https://gist.github.com/InQuize/59e7c458c510ae779743

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the pfSense source code [vpn_openvpn_client module](https://github.com/pfsense/pfsense/blob/master/src/usr/local/www/vpn_openvpn_client.php),

```
if ($tls_mode && $pconfig['tlsauth_enable'] && !$pconfig['autotls_enable']) {
        if (!strstr($pconfig['tls'], "-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----") ||
            !strstr($pconfig['tls'], "-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----")) {
            $input_errors[] = gettext("The field 'TLS Key' does not appear to be valid");
```

Basically what this does is check whether the 'TLS Key' field contains either "-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----" or "-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----", it doesn't verify that what you've pasted in there is a valid key. That's why you were able to clear the error when saving configuration, but the key still didn't work (giving you the "Non-Hex character "M" error.

I'm pretty sure you have to put the "BEGIN PRIVATE KEY" key into the Cert Manager (if using a key for identification). Combing through OpenVPN's documentation, their article on [hardening](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/hardening-openvpn-security/) says the TLS key is used to verify the origin of packets (implied to apply to all packets, control and data), whereas the key you have is used to identify the client for authentication. The TLS key is used to identify the *host*, whereas the key you have identifies the user.